# How to use quatifiers (* or +) in lookbehind regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning regex with lookaround (lookbehind and lookahead) feature but I cannot use `.*` or `.+` quantifiers in lookbehind (but I can on lookahead).

The regex I'm trying to fix is the following:

```
(?<!yellow.*)blue(?=.*brown)
```

The idea is to match lines that don't have `yellow` but has `blue` only if `brown` exists after blue. Here are some samples:

```
yellow blue brown                    // shouldn't match
f blue brown                         // should match
sdff blue brown                      // should match
asdf  f blue c                       // shouldn't match
yellow blue fblue b f brown          // shouldn't match
```

Here is my test:

http://regex101.com/r/fY4kI9/5

The error I get is:

> . * Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not
>   allowed

Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Which regex? Many (most?) regexes don't support variable length lookbehind. You can cheat some of them by using `{0, 100}` or the like.

Comment: You may need a compound regular expression...

Comment: What language/tool are you using here?

Comment: @anubhava I want the regex only not using any particular language.

Comment: @Fede that makes absolutely no sense. Regex is implemented by engines, and they have different capabilities. Saying you want the regex only is nonsensical. Even the link you provide to the tester has a "flavours" selector down the side that changes the engine being simulated.

Comment: @Fede: Different languages have different implementations; some support infinite-length lookbehinds, but some don't. If the regex flavor you're using *does* support it, the potential answers might change, too. That's why we're asking what platform you're using the regex on.

Comment: @AmalMurali good point, sorry for that. The idea is to implement it in java. I'll add the tag so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex without using variable length lookbehind but still getting the same functionality:

```
.*yellow.*(*SKIP)(*F)|^.*\bblue\b(?=.*brown).*$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fY4kI9/9)

Comment: Nice. But wouldn't this still match `sdff blue brown yellow`?

Comment: But that should match right? OP just doesn't want `yellow` before `blue` I think. Or did I misread it?

Comment: Also, this only matches ``blue`` but I think OP wants to match the whole line

Comment: "*The idea is to match lines that don't have yellow*" — As I understand it, the OP wants to match lines that doesn't contain `yellow`, and where `blue` is followed by `brown`.

Comment: Oh that's easy just add `.*` in the end i.e. `yellow.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\bblue\b(?=.*brown).*`

Comment: @anubhava needs one more edit to match the start of the line: ``.*yellow.*(*SKIP)(*F)|.*\bblue\b(?=.*brown).*`` (else in ``purple blue brown`` it just matches ``blue brown``)

Comment: @anubhava thatnks for the answer. Can you explain me a little bit more about that regex composition?

Comment: `(*F)` is a shorthand for `(*FAIL)` that behaves like a failing negative assertion and is a synonym for `(?!)`. `(*SKIP)` defines a point beyond which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack when the subpattern fails later. So  `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` together provide a nice alternative of restriction that you cannot have a variable length lookbehind in above regex.